# Underscore group Array with positif and zero value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, underscore.js

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB to generate this array:

```
[
{       
    "_id" : "588f7a15023333ac9efb5d4a",
    "id": "1",
    "data": { 
        "update_time" : "14:14:23" , 
        "speed" : "179" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "14:15:24" , 
        "speed" : "120" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:14:23" , 
        "speed" : "130" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:16:15" , 
        "speed" : "0" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:17:40" , 
        "speed" : "0" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:20:40" , 
        "speed" : "0" 
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:20:10" , 
        "speed" : "150"
        },
        { 
        "update_time" : "15:22:15" , 
        "speed" : "110" 
        }
        ...  
}
]
```

I want for a result a new array like this:

```
[
{   
    "_id" : "588f7a15023333ac9efb5d4a",
    "id": "1",
    "newData":  { 
                "time_spent" : "TOTAL TIME SPENT 1" , 
                "speed" : "AVERAGE SPEED 1"  //GROUP objects with positif speed
                },
                { 
                "time_spent" : "TOTAL TIME SPENT 2" , 
                "speed" : "0"  //GROUP objects with 0 speed
                }, 
                { 
                "time_spent" : "TOTAL TIME SPENT 3" , 
                "speed" : "AVERAGE SPEED 3"  //GROUP objects with positif speed
                }, 

                ...
}
]
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6sU.jpg)

I used underscore to do that but didn't have any success.

I spent two days trying to find a way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your actual expected output? Your pseudo-output is confusing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: can you show me what you want and from where you want.

Comment: First i thank you.
I add an image to describe the output. I want to create a new array grouping multiples objects contains **time_spent** and **speed average**. 
Each object is pushed when **speed changes from moving to stationary and reverse**.  I hope its understandable.

Comment: Corrected grammar.